# Loop Impacting Code Output using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I was wondering if someone could help me debug this my code. I can't seem to figure out why when the loop moves to the second row, it changes alters the elements within the array.

For example: if the array "BookMarksToDelete" has "Dog, Cat, Bird" in it, the second loop seem to want to make it "og, Cat, Bird" in the next row.

Is there a better approach to the loop?

```
For Each rw In myRange.Rows
    For Each cel In rw.Cells
        For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            Set oCell = myRange.Find(What:=myArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If oCell Is Nothing Then
                sTemp = sTemp & "," & myArray(i)
            Else
                Set oCell = Nothing
            End If
        Next i

        sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)

        If Not Len(Trim(sTemp)) = 0 Then
            BookMarksToDelete = Split(sTemp, ",")

            Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            wdApp.Visible = True
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

            For i = LBound(BookMarksToDelete) To UBound(BookMarksToDelete)
                Set pRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks(BookMarksToDelete(i)).Range
                pRng.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 2
                pRng.Delete
            Next i
        End If

        Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)
        For i = LBound(BookMarksToDelete) To UBound(BookMarksToDelete)
            For Each cell In myRangeRef
                If InStr(1, cell.Value, BookMarksToDelete(i), vbTextCompare) Then 
                    aCell = cell.Offset(, -1).Value
                    stTemp = stTemp & "," & aCell
                End If
            Next cell
        Next i

        stTemp = Mid(stTemp, 2)
        If Not Len(Trim(stTemp)) = 0 Then
            ReturnsToDelete = Split(stTemp, ",")
            For i = LBound(ReturnsToDelete) To UBound(ReturnsToDelete)
                For j = wdTable.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                    If Left(wdTable.cell(j, 1).Range.Text, Len(wdTable.cell(j, 1).Range.Text) - 2) = ReturnsToDelete(i) Then wdTable.Rows(j).Delete
                Next j
            Next i
        End If

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Investors Database")
            firstName = .Range("B" & rw)
            lastName = .Range("A" & rw)
            titleName = lastName & ", " & firstName
        End With

        Set tRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks("TitlePageName").Range
            tRng.Text = wdDoc.Bookmarks("TitlePageName").Range.Text & titleName
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "TitlePageName", tRng

        d = "Information Up-To-Date as of " & Date
        Set dRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks("TitlePageDate").Range
            dRng.Text = wdDoc.Bookmarks("TitlePageDate").Range.Text & d
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "TitlePageDate", dRng

        Set wRng = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FundCommentary").Range
        wRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        wRng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

        Set sRng = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Disclaimer").Range
        sRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        sRng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

        wdDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Update
        wdDoc.Repaginate

        With wdApp.ActiveDocument
            .SaveAs2 "https://websitefolder//document.docx"
            .Close
        End With

        wdApp.Visible = False

    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example: if the array "BookMarksToDelete" has `Dog, Cat, Bird` in it, the second loop seem to want to make it `og, Cat, Bird` in the next row.

When the loop runs for the 1st time, the value of `sTemp` is `""` so `sTemp = sTemp & "," & myArray(i)` adds a `,` at the beginning and then `sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)` trims off the `,` from the beginning.

When the code loops for the 2nd time, the value of `sTemp` is NOT `""` but your code in the next line `sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)` chops of the 1st letter.

**OPTION 1**: Resetting the `sTemp`

At the end of the code add the line `sTemp = ""`

**OPTION 2**: If you do not want to reset the `sTemp` then check whether the 1st character is a `,` or not

Replace `sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)` with `If Left(sTemp, 1) = "," Then sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)`

Comment: Need your help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787615/dictionary-doesnt-display-items-for-certain-key-numeric-value

Comment: Sorry. Was having my dinner. Seems like it is solved?